# How do I consistently set Local Date in Power BI so that it works in both desktop and PBI Service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am creating a report in Power BI that filters records based on the Current Date (e.g. only show records up to the Current Date).

When I create the Current Data field in Power Query, I use:

`CurrentDate = DateTimeZone.FixedLocalNow()`

To extract the current Date / Time to use in my filters.  However, when I publish to the PBI Service, it is returning a Date / Time from the previous day due to the difference in the timezones of the local servers - Desktop is running on Australia (Sydney) time, whereas the PBI service is run on UTC.

I have tried the following fix, but get the same results:

`CurrentDate = DateTime.From(DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(DateTimeZone.FixedLocalNow(),10))`

How do I set a current date in Power BI so that it consistently reports the Current Date / Time for the locale where the report is being used - i.e. it stays at the local time zone (UTC +9 / +11 depending upon DST) when viewed in both PBI Desktop and in PBI Service?

Comment: I think your power query is wrong can you try Current date  = DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(DateTimeZone.LocalNow(),10,0)

Comment: Will give that a try and let you know.  Unfortunately I generally don't get confirmation that a solution works until after midnight local (UTC +11)!

Comment: Well, it hasn't broken things, so here's fingers crossed...

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately - still offset until UTC ticks over midnight.  I may just download a system date from SQL (set to local) into Power BI and reference that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can be challenging to obtain a datetime zone that respects daylight savings. One solution I frequently use is the function below. By providing the offset for summertime and wintertime, it returns the correct local time zone for you.

```
(Summer_GMT_Offset as number, Winter_GMT_Offset as number) =>
let
    UTC_DateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UtcNow(),
    UTC_Date = Date.From( UTC_DateTimeZone ),
    StartSummerTime = Date.StartOfWeek( #date( Date.Year( UTC_Date ) , 3 , 31 ), Day.Sunday ),
    StartWinterTime = Date.StartOfWeek( #date( Date.Year( UTC_Date ) , 10, 31 ), Day.Sunday ),
    UTC_Offset = if UTC_Date >= StartSummerTime and UTC_Date < StartWinterTime then Summer_GMT_Offset else Winter_GMT_Offset,
    CET_Timezone = DateTimeZone.SwitchZone( UTC_DateTimeZone, UTC_Offset)
in
    CET_Timezone
```

You can find a step-by-step explanation of this function here: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/last-refresh-datetime/.

The crucial point is that DateTimeZone.UtcNow provides a fixed value (https://powerquery.how/datetimezone-utcnow/).

By determining whether the current date falls in the winter or summertime period, the function adjusts the timezone offset accordingly using DateTimeZone.SwitchZone (https://powerquery.how/datetimezone-switchzone/).

Cheers, Rick